# Why pdf is not opening with file object

Tags: javascript, pdf

Hi i'm facing the problem of opening a `pdf` with file object

i'm getting this error

> failed to load pdf document
>
> Reload

here what i have tried:

```
<iframe id="pdfiframe" src=""><iframe>

document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change',(event)=>{ 
     const file = event.target.files[0];
     let url = URL.createObjectURL( file );
     document.getElementById('pdfiframe').setAttribute('src',url);
},false);
```

Comment: What browser are you using? if it's firefox, type `about:config` in address bar, search 
 `pdfjs.disabled` . set this preference to `false`. Restart browser and try it again.

Comment: @Taurz i'm using chrome `101.0.4951.41`

Comment: The code is fine in my opinion，have you tried any other pdf files or browsers, did them all go wrong?

Comment: @Taurz i have tried with different pdf files which are opening fine in with other app, but not opening with above method.

Comment: @Taurz even i can see the src url which looks something like this  `blob:http://localhost:8080/48244c36-632c-4c56-9649-ac4b100a2a1a`   and there is no any issues or logs of cross origin